# Pattern Matching with float (Double type) in F#

Tags: f#, floating-point, pattern-matching, double

Can anyone explain why F# doesn't seem to like floats (type Double) in pattern maching expressions?

```ml
let intDiv x y =
    match x / y with
    | 5 -> printfn "Result was five - congrats"; 5
    | z -> printfn "Result was something else: %i" z; z
```

Matching `int` type: works as intended.

```ml
let floatDiv x y =
    match x / y with
    | nan      -> printfn "Homie, what did you even do?"; nan
    | infinity -> printfn "Wow, you got infinity!"; infinity
    | 5.0      -> printfn "Result was 5 - proud of you"; 5.0
    | z        -> printfn "Result was something else: %i" z; z
```

Here the match case `nan` will be matched every time, and the compiler also warns me about this—however, it will seemingly also return the correct result. I only expected this if it matched the last case `z`.

```ml
> floatDiv 10. 3.;;
Homie, what did you even do?
val it : float = 3.333333333
```

Comment: My own idea: it matches `nan` as a variable name instead of the floating point constant. Is this intended behaviour of a bug in the language?

Comment: You need something like this: let (|NaN|_|) value = if Single.IsNaN value then Some () else None

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you observed `nan` and `infinity` are treated as identifiers here and the value is bound to them.

If check the F# specification: https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf

Chapter 7 (page 115) says that a `const` expression is a pattern.

Chapter 4 (page 36) says that a `const` includes `ieee64`.

Chapter 3 (page 29) says that a `ieee64` is either a `float` or an integer followed by `LF`

At the sample place we find the definition for `float`.

```
token float =        
   digit+ . digit*         
   digit+ (. digit* )? (e|E) (+|-)? digit+
```

This definition only covers cases like 123, 3.14, 1E99 and so on. It doesn't include infinity nor nan.

So per the specification the above behavior is the intended. Should it be changed? Perhaps but involves update the language to include nan and infinity as part of the constant expressions for float. As `ieee` do include those values it makes sense I think that it should be part of the constant expression.

However, the change is likely risky as suddenly in old code `nan` meant a reference to method, with the change it will be a float literal. Maybe someone used nan as a function name? That would now crash because that would be like giving a function the name: `0`.

As mentioned by @Foole you could solve this using Active Patterns.

```
// Define the Active Pattern
let (|Float|Infinity|NaN|) n =
  if System.Double.IsPositiveInfinity   n then Infinity true
  elif System.Double.IsNegativeInfinity n then Infinity false
  elif System.Double.IsNaN              n then NaN
  else Float n

// We can then use the Active Pattern as a "smart" pattern
let floatDiv x y =
  match x / y with
  | NaN          -> printfn "Homie, what did you even do?"; nan
  | Infinity _   -> printfn "Wow, you got infinity!"; infinity
  | Float    5.0 -> printfn "Result was 5 - proud of you"; 5.0
  | Float    z   -> printfn "Result was something else: %f" z; z

let run () =
  floatDiv 1.0 2.0 |> printfn "%A"
  floatDiv 5.0 1.0 |> printfn "%A"
  floatDiv 1.0 0.0 |> printfn "%A"
  floatDiv 0.0 0.0 |> printfn "%A"
```

Comparing float numbers to a specific number is always a bit "risky" as floating numbers by their nature are often just an approximate answer. Usually one compare the result with a tolerance range.

In addition; nan confuses many developers in that most comparisons involving nan are false.

```
1.0 < nan // false  <-|
nan < 1.0 // false, <-| these inequalities can break balanced trees algorithms if you use float as a key and happen to insert a nan

nan = nan  // false  <-|
nan <> nan // true   <-| perhaps also surprising?
```